# How to manually calculate XML signature in C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I know there is a [SignedXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xwex4b(v=vs.110).aspx) class for signing XML document. However I am trying to calculate the signature value on my own, to understand what exactly is happening. More exactly, I am trying to sign a soap:Body element of SOAP message.
I have manually crated the Signature tag so it matches the template. Also I have succesfully calculated the digest of  and inserted this value into DigestValue tag. However I am not able to calculate correct value for the SigantureValue tag.

My approach is:

1. Canonicalize the SignedInfo tag using excl n14n transform
2. Hash the canonicalized data using SHA256
3. Use RSACryptoServiceProvider to sign the hash value

My code looks something like this:

```
  // 1 Canonicalize the SignedInfo tag 
  XmlDsigExcC14NTransform serializer = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  string toBeCanonicalized = signedInfoTag.OuterXml;
  doc.LoadXml(toBeCanonicalized);
  serializer.LoadInput(doc);
  string c14n = new StreamReader((Stream)serializer.GetOutput(typeof(Stream))).ReadToEnd();

  // 2 Hash the SignedInfo tag

  SHA256 HashAlg = SHA256.Create();
  byte[] hash = HashAlg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c14n));

  // 3 Sign the hash

  byte[] signature;
  using (RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
  {
    csp.ImportParameters(((RSACryptoServiceProvider)mCertificate.PrivateKey).ExportParameters(true));
    signature = csp.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c14n), "SHA256");
  }
  signValueTag.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
```

What I am doing wrong?

The example of valid SOAP message is here:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-A72D6FD4C41B1F545F14700558816386">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-A72D6FD4C41B1F545F147005588163810">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-A72D6FD4C41B1F545F14700558816389">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>iiyihYsFMjO7QxIVCauydehAhjSm5LZlRGm3lT0VFY0=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>cGbhgNKCwrmUPXg2AKgqs1mceNcywK8BvrmmrOH627/3vadzKVnPiTn6ZaLBAcV1pYgTpNvh7RvAa8uZYXmS77YCQcYIOErbWKSTDVwBWv63d8fLm9Ljpx/1/PZrI7zSeIafXTLwPB2Lzt239ylZWPdhfg9XMhS43k4p7u1DZerVeRNSi76Q8u6jIWadDIQkn9mVEbhL5RIRGPoGJBof9QQVk42NHChdESW2RFXG7SSs2VYmdZ+IQUdEC7uPFoT/vxK2My1hGhYhvl6HNbMd5VIz/xMlDPrOCzbLWkA7oqyqSboTCObwkTwD2V20sxn6rb8mtak55zYaGXJldno66g==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-A72D6FD4C41B1F545F14700558816387">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STR-A72D6FD4C41B1F545F14700558816388">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-A72D6FD4C41B1F545F14700558816386" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-A72D6FD4C41B1F545F14700558816389">
    <Trzba xmlns="http://fs.mfcr.cz/eet/schema/v3">
      <Hlavicka dat_odesl="2016-09-19T19:06:37+02:00" prvni_zaslani="false" uuid_zpravy="f5ce1350-e688-4247-b1af-3d2bc592b83c"/>
      <Data celk_trzba="34113.00" cerp_zuct="679.00" cest_sluz="5460.00" dan1="-172.39" dan2="-530.73" dan3="975.65" dat_trzby="2016-08-05T00:30:12+02:00" dic_popl="CZ1212121218" id_pokl="/5546/RO24" id_provoz="273" porad_cis="0/6460/ZQ42" pouzit_zboz1="784.00" pouzit_zboz2="967.00" pouzit_zboz3="189.00" rezim="0" urceno_cerp_zuct="324.00" zakl_dan1="-820.92" zakl_dan2="-3538.20" zakl_dan3="9756.46" zakl_nepodl_dph="3036.00"/>
      <KontrolniKody>
        <pkp cipher="RSA2048" digest="SHA256" encoding="base64">D84gY6RlfUi8dWdhL1zn0LE0s+aqLohtIxY0y88GoG5Ak8pBEH3/Ff2aFW7H6fvRxDMKsvM/VIYtUQxoDEctVGMSU/JDf9Vd0eQwgfLm683p316Sa4BUnVrIsHzwMyYkjpn66I072G2AvOUP4X5UiIYtHTwyMVyp+N/zzay3D7Q619ylDb6puN2iIlLsu+GNSB9DvsQbiLXPH6iK0R9FpR15v2y+0Uhh8NNJKl7O8Us9jbgokrA9gze+erQbhmwTm2nn2+7JGrPDqhyhwWZNLUziGSbC99wJpkEnIs0das/4hFNE3DnLvv4MsXwWCLOUZty6t6DAijlCzQj7KFKw0g==</pkp>
        <bkp digest="SHA1" encoding="base16">8F8ABFEB-B76E7064-343A1460-6C6E6D86-B0F99C24</bkp>
      </KontrolniKody>
    </Trzba>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Sha and RSA are different algorithms.  Don't mix.  See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

After banging my head against the wall trying to encrypt, hash, sign, with the certificate keys, I decided to check if there was some source code available for the [SignedXml](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/xml/signedxml.cs) class. Thank God there is a [reference source for .NET](https://referencesource.microsoft.com). So I went to the [SignedXml.ComputeSignature](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/xml/signedxml.cs,ec07e01153e4b893,references) method, to see how it worked. **TL;DR**, here is the code, based on those sources:

```
// Get signature description (using signature method algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256)
var signatureDescription
  = System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA256Url) as System.Security.Cryptography.SignatureDescription;
if (signatureDescription == null)
  throw new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException("SignatureDescriptionNotCreated");

// Get hash algorithm from signature description
System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm hashAlg = signatureDescription.CreateDigest();
if (hashAlg == null)
  throw new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException("CreateHashAlgorithmFailed");

// Load SignedInfo OuterXml in a separate XmlDocument, and canonicalize
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
string toBeCanonicalized = signedInfoTag.OuterXml;
doc.LoadXml(toBeCanonicalized);
var transform = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
transform.LoadInput(doc);
byte[] hashvalue = transform.GetDigestedOutput(hashAlg);  // hashvalue is not used, but I
                                                          // think this process allows to
                                                          // use hashAlg to get the
                                                          // SignatureValue later

// Create signature formatter using certificate's private key
System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricSignatureFormatter asymmetricSignatureFormatter
  = signatureDescription.CreateFormatter(mCertificate.PrivateKey);

// Get signature value
byte[] signatureValueBytes = asymmetricSignatureFormatter.CreateSignature(hashAlg);

// Set signature value to node text, as Base64 string
signValueTag.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureValueBytes)
```

Comment: what are signedInfoTag and signValueTag ?

Comment: I have an exception that "Invalid alghoritm specified", can you tell me why? :)

Comment: @Kamil `signedInfoTag` is the `<ds:SignedInfo>` tag in the SOAP message, and `signValueTag` is the `<ds:SignatureValue>` tag. About the "Invalid alghoritm specified", in which line do you get that error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
string toBeCanonicalized = signedInfoTag.InnerXml;
```

instead of

```
string toBeCanonicalized = signedInfoTag.OuterXml;
```

Complete code:

```
// 1 Canonicalize the SignedInfo tag 
XmlDsigExcC14NTransform serializer = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string toBeCanonicalized = signedInfoTag.InnerXml;
doc.LoadXml(toBeCanonicalized);
serializer.LoadInput(doc);
string c14n = new StreamReader((Stream)serializer.GetOutput(typeof(Stream))).ReadToEnd();

// 2 Hash the SignedInfo tag
SHA256 HashAlg = SHA256.Create();
byte[] hash = HashAlg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c14n));

// 3 Sign the hash
byte[] signature;
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    csp.ImportParameters(((RSACryptoServiceProvider)mCertificate.PrivateKey)
       .ExportParameters(true));
    signature = csp.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c14n), "SHA256");
}
signValueTag.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
```